# While using joblib.Parallel and partial, would the hidden parameters be copied?

Tags: python-3.x, joblib, functools

Suppose I have 2 Python functions: `funcA` and `funcB`. `funcA` takes a `large_data` as input which is generated in `funcB`. And `funcA` is called within `funcB` many times. I would like to use `joblib.Parallel` to speed up the calculation. My question is if I use `partial` as follows, would this `large_data` be copied to the different nodes? If yes, can you elaborate on it? If not, what is the proper way of handling this `large_data`?

```
def funcA(large_data, key):
    ...
    return val


def funcB(list_keys, param)
    large_data = some_function(param)
    tmp_func = partial(funcA, large_data=large_data)
    list_res = Parallel(n_jobs)(delayed(tmp_func)(key) for key in list_keys)
    return list_res
```

Comment: By default, `joblib.Parallel` creates subprocesses.  Those processes will need a copy of all of the data.  If you are on LInux, then subprocesses are created by forking, which uses read-only duplicate pages to create the new process, and does not result in a copy.  If you are on Windows, then the data will have to be copied.